# Why am I getting an error when trying to call a method with flutter chopper and built value?

Tags: json, flutter, built-value, chopper

I'm getting The below ERROR,I believe it's because of null safety, this means that no data has been received or getSignedInUser() method is incorrect or class **BuiltValueConverter** is the cause.

(I tested the token with Postman and retrieved the data)

> E/flutter (21792): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)]
> Unhandled Exception: Unhandled error Null check operator used on a
> null value occurred in Instance of 'AuthBloc'. E/flutter (21792): #0
> BuiltValueConverter._deserialize
> package:todo_list_app/…/auth/built_value_converter.dart:51 E/flutter
> (21792): #1      BuiltValueConverter._convertToCustomObject
> package:todo_list_app/…/auth/built_value_converter.dart:36 E/flutter
> (21792): #2      BuiltValueConverter.convertResponse
> package:todo_list_app/…/auth/built_value_converter.dart:25

I'm using chopper with built_value Pubs. i'm trying to convert the coming json to object.
Example:

> {
> "userName": "Jack",
> "email": "jack2066@gmail.com",
> "userRole": "USER",
> "created_at": "2021-07-03T16:49:56.774Z",
> "updated_at": "2021-07-03T16:49:56.774Z" }

the below code where the error start also explained in this Tutorial [Converters & Built Value Integration](https://resocoder.com/2019/07/14/chopper-retrofit-for-flutter-3-converters-built-value-integration/)

```
import 'package:built_collection/built_collection.dart';
import 'package:chopper/chopper.dart';
import 'package:todo_list_app/infrastructure/remote/auth/models/serializers.dart';

class BuiltValueConverter extends JsonConverter {

  @override
  Request convertRequest(Request request) {
    return super.convertRequest(
      request.copyWith(
        body: serializers.serializeWith(
          serializers.serializerForType(request.body.runtimeType)!,
          request.body,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Response<BodyType> convertResponse<BodyType, SingleItemType>(
    Response response,
  ) {
    final Response dynamicResponse = super.convertResponse(response);
    final BodyType customBody =
        _convertToCustomObject<SingleItemType>(dynamicResponse.body);//
    return dynamicResponse.copyWith<BodyType>(body: customBody);
  }


  dynamic _convertToCustomObject<SingleItemType>(dynamic element) {
    if (element is SingleItemType) return element;

    if (element is List)
      return _deserializeListOf<SingleItemType>(element);
    else
      return _deserialize<SingleItemType>(element);
  }

  BuiltList<SingleItemType> _deserializeListOf<SingleItemType>(
    List dynamicList,
  ) {
    // Make a BuiltList holding individual custom objects
    return BuiltList<SingleItemType>(
      dynamicList.map((element) => _deserialize<SingleItemType>(element)),
    );
  }

  SingleItemType _deserialize<SingleItemType>(Map<String, dynamic> value,) {
    // We have a type parameter for the BuiltValue type, which should be returned after deserialization.
    return serializers.deserializeWith(
      serializers.serializerForType(SingleItemType)!, // Error Start
      value,
    );
  }

}
```

Here is my Chopper service code, **getSignedInUser** throw the error.
I don't know if the implementation of the **getSignedInUser** method is correct or not.

```
import 'package:chopper/chopper.dart';
import 'package:injectable/injectable.dart';
import 'package:todo_list_app/infrastructure/remote/auth/built_value_converter.dart';
import 'package:todo_list_app/infrastructure/remote/auth/models/auth_built_model.dart';
import 'package:todo_list_app/infrastructure/remote/core/constants.dart';

part 'auth_service.chopper.dart';

@singleton
@ChopperApi() 
abstract class AuthService extends ChopperService {
  @factoryMethod
  static AuthService create() {
    final client = ChopperClient(
      baseUrl: AUTH_BASE_URL_External,
      services: [
        _$AuthService(),
      ],
      converter: BuiltValueConverter(),
      errorConverter: JsonConverter(),
      interceptors: [
        HttpLoggingInterceptor()
      ],
    );
    return _$AuthService(client);
  }

  @Post(path: '/signup')
  Future<Response> signUp(@Body() RegisterRequestModel body);

  @Post(path: '/signin')
  Future<Response<LoginResponseModel>> singIn(@Body() LoginRequestModel body);

  //headers: {AUTH_HEADER:BEARER+'authValue'}
  @Get(path: '/auth', )//authValue='Bearer Token'
  Future<Response<UserResponseModel>> getSignedInUser(@Header("Authorization") String authValue);//error Unhandled error Null check operator used on a null value
}
```

Any idea how to solve this Error?
also Is there a good documentation for Chopper or alternative pub with a good documentation?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing values in your "serielizers.dart" file it should be as followed :

```
    @SerializersFor(const[RegisterRequestModel,LoginRequestModel,UserResponseModel])
final Serializers serializers =
(_$serializers.toBuilder()..addPlugin(StandardJsonPlugin())).build();
```

Comment: I tried to check my old code but it's already modified , but maybe that I forget to add "UserResponseModel", Thanks for advice

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, as you said it's because of null safety. Your `_deserialize` returns a non-null value whereas the `serializers.deserializeWith` can return a null value. Either you can change the return type to be nullable, or handle the null case for `serializers.deserializeWith`. If you want you can use the below `BuiltValueConverter`. It is from the [example](https://github.com/lejard-h/chopper/blob/master/example/bin/main_built_value.dart) which they have given which is generic, with minor changes.

```
import 'package:built_collection/built_collection.dart';
import 'package:built_value/serializer.dart';
import 'package:chopper/chopper.dart';
import 'package:graphical_representation/app/serializers.dart';

class BuiltValueConverter extends JsonConverter {
  T? _deserialize<T>(dynamic value) => serializers.deserializeWith<T>(
    (serializers.serializerForType(T) as Serializer<T>),
    value,
  );

  BuiltList<T> _deserializeListOf<T>(Iterable value) => BuiltList(
    value.map((value) => _deserialize<T>(value)).toList(growable: false),
  );

  dynamic _decode<T>(entity) {
    /// handle case when we want to access to Map<String, dynamic> directly
    /// getResource or getMapResource
    /// Avoid dynamic or unconverted value, this could lead to several issues
    if (entity is T) return entity;

    try {
      if (entity is List) return _deserializeListOf<T>(entity);
      return _deserialize<T>(entity);
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Response<ResultType> convertResponse<ResultType, Item>(Response response) {
    // use [JsonConverter] to decode json
    final jsonRes = super.convertResponse(response);
    final body = _decode<Item>(jsonRes.body);
    return jsonRes.copyWith<ResultType>(body: body);
  }

  @override
  Request convertRequest(Request request) => super.convertRequest(
    request.copyWith(
      body: serializers.serialize(request.body),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply and the info, but  I think it's more about chopper problem, because I had used DIO & Retrofit and the code work fine.